# How to find and replace numeric rows in a character vector?

Tags: r

I would like to know how to exclude rows, which have only numbers as content in a character vector. I would like to keep variables of the following format:

```
                               123_john-dallas
                               222_Michael Berlin
                               45678_thomas-Karlsruhe
```

And remove data with the following format:

```
                                122345
                                12567:1992
                                120388;20:34
                                394,21:33
```

from one single character vector. The common theme in the required format seems to be the underscore '_' Therefore I tried unsuccessfully capture it:

Some data:

```
                        seed(1000)

                        string<- function(n=1000, lenght=10)
                         {
                                   random <- c(1:n)                  
                                   for (i in 1:n)
                         {
                         random[i] <- paste(sample(c("AbcD","_", 1:9),
                                lenght, replace=TRUE),
                                collapse="")
                                          }
                          return(random)
                         }
                         characterNumber<-string()

                        character<-grep(characterVector,'_')
```

But I get just an empty vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep all values containing `_`, you can use `grep` like this :

```
characterNumber[grep("_", characterNumber)]
```

Alternatively, if you want to exclude all the elements containing numbers, `:`, `;` or `,`, you can try something like this :

```
characterNumber[!grepl("^[0-9:;,]+$", characterNumber)]
```

Comment: May I kindly ask you to expand your answer just for a case where I would deal with data frames. If keeping "_" I would also like to keep the rows from other attributes which correspond to row 123_Michael

Comment: You want to keep rows if they contain a `-` in at least one of several columns ?

Comment: Given a data frame with id(123_michael) age(32) skills(5). If deleting all rows other that  _ I would also like to delete the corresponding rows from age and skills. If keeping all rows with _ I would like to keep the corresponding rows from age and skills...sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Then just use data frame indexing : `df[grep("_", df$id), ]`.

Answer (score 1):

if `mystr` is your character vector, you can try asking to keep only strings that contains letters:

```
mystr[grepl("[a-zA-Z]", mystr)]
```

*Example*

```
mystr <- c("123_john-dallas", "222_Michael Berlin", "45678_thomas-Karlsruhe","122345", "12567:1992", "120388;20:34", "394,21:33")

mystr[grepl("[a-zA-Z]", mystr)]
#[1] "123_john-dallas"        "222_Michael Berlin"     "45678_thomas-Karlsruhe"
```